# stretching curve to reach point python

Tags: python, line, stretch

I have a curve and I want to fix the starting point and drag the end point to the blue dot while maintaining the the general shape of the curve (stretching and contracting it). Any thoughts how I might do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10)

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

pl.plot(x, f(x))

pl.plot(8,.2,'bo')
```

[Curve with Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRqJf.png)

## ANSWER

```
#shift the end point to the dot
shift_x = 10-x[-1]
shift_y = .2-y[-1]


#shift the data
x=x+shift_x
y=y+shift_y

pl.plot(x,y)
pl.plot(10,.2,'bo')
```

[shift end point to desired location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZdNP.png)

```
#shift the data back to the original points based on how close it is
#to the end point
gradient_x = shift_x/len(x)
gradient_y = shift_y/len(y)

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = y[i]-(len(x)-i)*gradient_y
    x[i] = x[i]-(len(x)-i)*gradient_x

pl.plot(x,y)
pl.plot(10,.2,'bo')
```

[All 3 Tranformations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjEGu.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?  Maybe measure the distance at `x,y` from the current `y` to the desired `x,y` (at dot) and lengthen `x` accordingly?  Can you please give a bit on context on your project?

Comment: well whats going to need to happen is I need to squeeze the curve like a spring, I feel like there should be a simple algorithm to do this but im just plain stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple scale to stretch:

```
x_scale = (blue_x - x0) / (x1 - x0)
y_scale = (blue_y - y0) / (y1 - y0)
```

and then convert all points in the curve:

```
new_x = (old_x - x0) * x_scale + x0
new_y = (old_y - y0) * y_scale + y0
```

assuming (x0, y0) is the start of the curve.

Comment: @BenShapiro feel free to accept / upvote if you find it useful =)